# remove duplicates RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php

I was thinking of using RecursiveIteratorIterator to display the "top-directories", in my example layout and puffar, but I cannot get it to work. The structure is as follows:

```
| images |
  => layout
       =>lab
  => puffar
```

and the result is

```
layout
layout
layout
layout/lab
layout/lab
puffar
puffar


$directory = 'images';

    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory));

    while($it->valid()) {

    if (!$it->isDot()) {       
        echo $it->getSubPath() . "\n";       
    }

    $it->next();
    }
```

another thing that I cannot get to work is if I change the directory path to

```
$directory = 'newsletter.site.se/images';
```

it is not displaying anything. 
It would be fantasic if someone could help me. thanks linda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` if you just want to display the top directories?

Instead you could use:

```
<?php
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('.') as $entry) {
    if (!$entry->isDot() && $entry->isDir()) {
        echo $entry, '<br />';
    }
}
```

If you want all directories, try: (for example)

```
<?php
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($it as $entry) {
    if ($entry->isDir()) {
        echo $entry, '<br />';
    }
}
```

About your second question, have you checked that the path is correct and readable for php?