# How to get rid of duplicates from search in PHP

Tags: php

From inside one of the directories, I check whether there is a subdirectory with the given name ($taxon) in other directories (../nn). If so, I only need the name of the SINGLE appropriate directory (path) to display. The searched subdirectories with a given name may be located in several directories.

As a result of running the script, I get DOUBLE results (due to the files in the directories) - this is the path to the subdirectory with a name consistent with $taxon...

..\gallery_01\298089-2\
..\gallery_01\298089-2\

..\gallery_02a\298089-2\
..\gallery_02a\298089-2\

..\gallery_03bb\298089-2\
..\gallery_03bb\298089-2\

I would like to ask for the simplest possible solutions (to my puzzle). Thank you.

```php
<?php
$taxon = '298089-2';

$dir = '../'; //path of the directory to read

$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY) as $file) {

    if (!$file->isFile()) {

        $a=array($file);

        // we check whether the value of the $taxon variable is in the access path string
        foreach($a as  $value ) {

            $szukany = strpos ($value, $taxon);
            
            if ($szukany != null) { 
                echo "<BR><a href=". $file->getPath().">" . $file->getPath() . "\</a><BR>";
            }  
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this site don't show "backslash" in  "..\gallery_01\298089-2". In  the original all tracks end with a backslash like "..\gallery_01\298089-2\".

Comment: It must be escaped. Fixed.

Comment: Why do you turn $file into an array and access it with a foreach??? . The *echo* statement is missing quotation marks for *href* attribute, it should be: `echo '<br><a href="' . $file->getPath() . '">' . $file->getPath() . '\</a><br>';`

Comment: This loose comparison is not reliable. `$szukany = strpos ($value, $taxon); if ($szukany != null) {`  You are not differentiating between `0` and `false`.  Also, `strpos()` doesn't return `null` so checking against `null` is only misleading to anyone who reads your code.

Comment: How about this cryptically titled page? [remove duplicates RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5990441/2943403)

Comment: Also, If you aren't going to html or url encode your strings, you can call `getPath()` just once with `printf('<br><a href="%1$s">%1$s\</a><br>', $file->getPath());`

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable tips. But still no one has written anything about DOUBLE results. I can't figure it out myself, but I can see that it's extremely difficult for all you too. If I'm not mistaken, these double results are related to links to "../directory/subdirectory/." and "../directory/subdirectory/.."

Comment: The right solusion is in "duplicate question", link at top